Static/Dynamic Replication of Range Accrual and TARF?
I am trying to understand how one can replicate (approximately, if not entirely) the pay off for a Range accrual note and FX TARF? There is generic literature, which refers Range Accrual as a series of sold Daily options but I am not able to figure out how?
Likewise, for a TARF - how would one go about replicating the pay off using the vanilla European options? I understand the structure knocks off once profit cap is accrued but can we say a series of buy calls on each fixing date and sold leverage puts on each fixing date would be good approximation to replicate TARF (ignoring the profit cap condition).

https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/80605/54838 without a cap or ki, TARFs are just a synthetic forward with leveraged downside leg. However, you will miss the core feature, which is the target.

Thanks, I went through it - only thing I am thinking is wont the a series of call options (across all fixing dates) and sold leveraged puts (across all fixing) would be a better representation?

Better than what? A synthetic forward is long a call and short a put. The leveraged downside is your put. The link I provided shows this graphically as well and explains that it's a strip.
